# Type Mismatch: inferred type is HomeViewModel! but ViewModel! was expected

Tags: android, kotlin

Good Afternoon All, I have an issue and im wondering what is causing it

My MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.albumapp.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.albumapp.R
import com.example.albumapp.data.PostModel
import com.example.albumapp.viewmodel.HomeViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var adapter: HomeAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        **var vm = ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]**

        initAdapter()

        vm.fetchAllPosts()

        vm.postModelListLiveData?.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it!=null){
                rv_home.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                adapter.setData(it as ArrayList<PostModel>)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            progress_home.visibility = View.GONE
        })

    }

    private fun initAdapter() {
        adapter = HomeAdapter(this)
        rv_home.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rv_home.adapter = adapter
    }


}
```

ViewModel.kt

```
class HomeViewModel {
    private var homeRepository:HomeRepository?=null
    var postModelListLiveData : LiveData<List<PostModel>>?=null

    init {
        homeRepository = HomeRepository()
        postModelListLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun fetchAllPosts(){
        postModelListLiveData = homeRepository?.fetchAllPosts()
    }
}
```

Im wondering why is there being a type mismatch being caused and how do you go about to fix this type mismatch?
(The line with two stars is where the issue is being caused)

Comment: Can you include your code for your `HomeViewModel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HomeViewModel should extend ViewModel like this

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
}
```

then try this

```
var homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: post your viewmodel class as well

Comment: ive added it for you now